# How can I plot a bar plot grouped by month and year using matpltlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is my code:

```
plt.bar(df.index, df['January'])
plt.bar(df.index, df['February'])
```

This is the figure that I get:

[image]

How can I get the orange and blue bars side-by-side?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pandas' plotting function:

```
df.plot.bar(y=['January','February'])
```

Or manually align the bars:

```
width=0.4
plt.bar(df.index, df['January'], width=-width, align='edge')
plt.bar(df.index, df['February'], width=width, align='edge')
```

Comment: I used that before, but is there a way I can use matplotlib.pyplot for this ?

Comment: with `plt` you need to manually align the bars. See updated. And it works for two columns only. For more columns, you need to shift the bars accordingly.